# graph api response failure cases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Graph SDK in asp.net to create users as here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

I see the json response there, but there is no documentation on failure cases. For example, what is the response when password is too weak? I need to handle all these scenarios but I don't see any documentation except for the ideal case response.

Answer (score 0):

The following Microsoft Docs page lists detailed error responses and also indicates that some detailed information about errors may be returned as part of a JSON error response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors

There is some interesting detailed error codes shown there, but I do not see anything specific to weak passwords.

If you force a test case with a weak password and using the information presented on the page I linked, perhaps you can find the details within the JSON error response that are specific to a weak-password condition.

Comment: I am not seeing any error code except for "Bad Request", but the message says something along the lines of "Password complexity requirements are not met. Please supply a different password."